How to batch import geotagged photos into QGIS?
I did some flights with a DJI drone over an area a few kilometers long, and I would like to batch import the hundreds of geotagged photos into QGIS. I have tried the ImportPhotos Plugin but the photos only show up as point symbols, but I want the images themselves to show up on the map.
Alternatively, is there a way to mosaic all the photos in QGIS and then import the mosaic as a single layer?



step: use the processing tool import geotagged photos



step: set the markers symbol layer type to raster image marker and use the data definded override and use the attribute photo to get the path and image file



step: adjust the size of the photos to meters in scale



How does it know the orientation of each photo?

it does not know the orientation, but you asked how to import photos in batch mode and show them as photos and not as points.

I want to know how to import them georectified as well

The images are geotagged and not georeferenced.  There is a QGIS plugin called Vertical Photo Placer that will at least rotate the images for display in QGIS but this resulting image would not be the same as the footprint of image as captured (and it only works on vertical images).
There are lots of GIS SE question about automatically georeferencing drone images. You may find that there are solutions that use CMOS sensor size, focal length, image size...in addition to the GNSS location to attempt to do that.  Unfortunately, consumer-grade IMU sensors and GNSS often result in questionable georeferencing quality.
